# How to deploy my java j2ee program in glassfish server ?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a java application that running every 15 min.
I want to deploy it under a GlassFish server.
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. Check [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html) for starters.

Also, in the IDE you can configure your Glassfish server and the IDE will automatically plug in deployment process for the project. All you would then have to do is to use Run / Run on Server.

Comment: A windows service for Glassfish Startup / Shutdown - Yes || 

A windows service for deployment - No

Comment: can you explain more ,

Comment: ?? Is your "how to deploy" or "how to deploy every 15 minutes"?